# permission denied target 'xyz' is not a directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, users

Please help with this question :

Create a new user called `hos` with password `123`. In the home directory of this user, create a file called `xyz`, containing a list of all files and directories from /etc that start with `a`.

Make sure the newly created user owns the file.
I am using this but it says `permission denied target ‘/home/hos/xyz’ is not a directory`

```
sudo adduser hos password 123
mkdir /home/hos/xyz
sudo cp -r /etc/a* /home/hos/xyz
```

Comment: sudo adduser hos password 123
mkdir /home/hos/xyz
sudo cp -r /etc/a* /home/hos/xyz
chown -R hos /home/hos/xyz

Comment: `mkdir` is for making directories. You should be trying to make a file that contains a list of all files and directories starting with `a` in `/etc`. You shouldn't be trying to make a directory called `xyz` with a copy of every folder and file starting with `a` inside.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question you need a few steps to solve that. As first you create a user and his username, add a group for him and add him to this group.

This you can do with one command or multiple commands, first the multiple approach where I add in comment lines for explanation:

```bsh
# adding a user hos with password 123 which you have provide by hand
# you can add the password into the line with the -p flag but you have
# provide the password in encrypted format then.
sudo adduser hos

# adding a group with the same name as the user
sudo addgroup hos

# adding the newly created user to this newly created group
sudo usermod -aG hos hos
```

Same you can achieve with only the `adduser` command like in the following line. For options on the `adduser` command see its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/adduser.8.html).

```
adduser --ingroup hos hos
```

Now to the second part of that question, creating a file containing the names of files in `/etc` which begin with `a`. This is simply achieved by listing the files with `ls /etc/a*`.

```
ls /etc/a* | sudo -u hos tee ~hos/xyz
```

This should be all.

Comment: You didn't create the group hos though?

Comment: You don't need to create the deault homedir, adduser usually creates a homedir in /home/ automatically using `/etc/skel` as it's template. Unless you specify `--no-create-home`.

Comment: [It is almost never a good idea to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In any case, it is not needed at all here, all you want is `ls /etc/a*`.

Comment: You should not need to take care of the primary group when you use `adduser` It automatically creates a group of the same name as the user and adds the user to it. You also don't need the `--ingroup`.